# Wordpress ya no me lee un shortcode

Tags: html, wordpress, plugin

En mi pagina **wordpress** de la noche a la mañana hay ciertos **,shortcodes** que no los lee correctamente https://www.mipodo.com/blog/companias-luz/
Y en vez de aparecer un cuadro azul con texto deslizante, me aparece:

```
[spb_icon_box title="Producto personalizado" box_type="animated-alt" 
    box_icon_type="svg" svg_icon="business-outline_award-48" animate_svg="yes"
    target="_self" animation="none" animation_delay="0" icon_color="#ffffff"
    text_color="#ffffff" bg_color="#06b8c1" flip_bg_color="#ffffff" 
    flip_text_color="#706f6f" animated_box_style="coloured" 
    animated_box_rounded="yes" width="1" el_position=""]

Pensamos en tu ahorro para que pagues lo mínimo por tu electricidad: al igual que una traje a medida, las ofertas de Podo también se ajustan a lo que realmente necesitas.

[/spb_icon_box]
```

Comment: Buenas Moises, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio. Es **muy importante** [edit] la pregunta para que tenga un formato claro. No uses un bloque de texto, dale estilo y separa en parrafos. Añade también más informacion siguiendo [ask] y [mcve] . un saludo!

Comment: Creo que el fallo esta en las comillas que encierran los valores: son diferentes en algunos valores